# How to use the modulus operator in division equations when the mod value is non-prime

Tags: math, modulus

I know that (a*b)%M = (a%M * b%M)%M

But what if the equation was :( (a*b)/c )%M ..I dont think I can use the above logic here also..And here M is a non-prime number ..You may assume that (a*b)/c will NEVER end up in a floating value..

```
For eg:
If a=10 b=9 and c=6,M=4 then (a*b)/c=15 and 15%4=3
but if I use the property as it is with multiplications then ((10%4*9%4)/(6%4))%4= (2*1)/2=1
```

Please tell me how to solve this kind of problem??

Comment: Maybe I'm just not smart enough, but I don't know what the question is. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I second that, it would be nice to know what you are trying to achieve. Other than that, I think this queston belongs to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If c and M were relatively prime, you could multiply c^-1%M and the math should work.  However, if GCD(c,M)>1, then c^-1%M doesn't exist, and there is no easy way to do it that I know of.

As far as what c^-1%M is, its the number such that c*c^-1%M=1.  For example, if c=2 and M=9, 2*5%9=10%9=1, so c^-1%M=5.

You can calculate c^-1%M with [the extended euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_euclidean_algorithm) -- you get ac+bM=1, so ac=1+(-b)M and ac%M=1.

Comment: Thanks ..And how will I store c^-1 in the program..It will require a double ..Or I dont need to do that and simply write (a%M*b%M*c^-1%M)%M??

Comment: Its an integer -- see my edit.  This is straying into discrete math (the sort used in cryptography).